# Grails 3 functional test

Tags: grails, functional-programming

I am trying to upgrade my application from grails 2 to grails 3. However, the functional test which is working in grails 2 fails to run now. In grails 2, I use RestBuilder to send request and get response. In grails 3, there is no corresponding RestBuilder release. How can I send my post and get request in grails 3 functional test?

Thanks very much.

My test code in grails 2:

```
 void testRequestNewEnvironment() {
    setup:
    def rest = new RestBuilder(connectTimeout:1000, readTimeout:20000)
    int timeout = 10
    String environmentId = 0
    String environmentStatus = "Not Ready"

    when:
    /**
     * PostMethod. Send out a post and response status should be 200 and the body of response include env_id
     */
    def resp = rest.post('http://localhost:8080/test-environment-manager/environment') {
        contentType "multipart/form-data"
        buildfile= new File('script.sh')
        username = "apps"
        keepEnvflag = "false"
        env_flavor = "default"
    }

    then:
    resp.getStatus() == 200
    environmentId = resp.json.env_id
    println "Environment ID: $environmentId"
    println ("Environment Status"+resp.json.Status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `RESTClient` for executing HTTP requests in Grails functional tests. It's a class from the  HTTPBuilder library, so it should work in every Grails version (because it has dependency on Grails).

Some example usages are shown [here](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient). Before you can use it, you'll need to add a dependency on this library by adding the following to `build.gradle`

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
```

Comment: Hi, First thank you for your answer. However, when I add "compile ":rest:0.8"" or "compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.0""   in the build.gradle. The server always fails to start. the error message is :  Error initializing classpath: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultModuleVersionSelector

Comment: @sspqingda try adding this instead `compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'`

Comment: Thanks. compile "org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:2.0.0"  also works.

Comment: hi When I use the RESTClient. it could recognize the requestContentType:muti-part/form-data

Comment: @sspqingda `compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'` and `compile "org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:2.0.0"` are not the same. In the former case, you're adding a library dependency whereas in the latter case you're adding a plugin dependency

Answer (score 0):

I added :

compile ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1"

and it works fine.